# SQL join one table against multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I am having 2 tables in my DB

1) Report table

```
 AppNo AppName AddedBy AssignedTo ModifiedBy
 -------------------------------------------
    1   App1       1        2           1      
    2   App2       1        2           2
    3   App3       2        2           2
    4   App4       1        2           3
```

2) Users table

```
   UserId  UserName Role
   ----------------------
    1     Raj      Manager
    2     Sid      Lead
    3     KK       Rep
```

So i want to join two tables so that i can get names in place of Id's

**Result Needed:**

```
  AppNo AppName AddedBy AssignedTo ModifiedBy
  -------------------------------------------
    1   App1     Raj      Sid          Raj      
    2   App2     Raj      Sid          Sid
    3   App3     Sid      Sid          Sid
    4   App4     Raj      Sid           KK
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT
R.AppNo, R.AppName,
u1.UserName as AddedBy,
u2.UserName as AssignedTo,
u3.UserName as ModifiedBy

FROM Report R

LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u1 on u1.UserID = R.AddedBy
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u2 on u2.UserID = R.AssignedTo
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u3 on u3.UserID = R.ModifiedBy
```

But i dont want to join multiple time with User table..

As in my original report table there are nearly 8 UserId columns are there so i cant join 8 times it reduces performance.

Can anyone suggest the best way.

**Note:** I cant change table schema

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Joining multiple times is the only way; that is what the data and structure is.

There should be no performance issue, as the database is typically well designed to handle this. Just because a JOIN looks complex to humans doesn't mean it is complex or expensive for the optimizer or the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cartesian join for the columns, although performance will depend heavily on how well indexed the tables are...

```
select R.AppNo,
       R.AppName,
       (select UserName from Users where UserID = R.AddedBy) as AddedBy,
       (select UserName from Users where UserID = R.AssignedTo) as AssignedTo,
       (select UserName from Users where UserID = R.ModifiedBy) as ModifiedBy
from Report R
```